# Discord.Py: Can't rename channel and don't have any exceptions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to rename the channel every 5 seconds to create animation. And when I am using code below, it works were slowly and renames the channel in one minute or more.

```py
from asyncio import sleep
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '(HIDEN)'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

async def voice_channel_animation():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = bot.get_guild(821422769144594472).get_channel(822470935243128872)
    animation = [" Create channel", " Create channel", " Create channel"]
    size = len(animation)
    while True:
        await channel.edit(name=animation[counter])
        counter = 0 if counter + 1 == size else counter + 1
        await sleep(5)

bot.loop.create_task(voice_channel_animation())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Any time that you are trying to do something that involves using the Internet, and the problem is "I can do this, but not as often as I'd like", the *first* thing you should ask is "how often does the service on the other end of the Internet connection allow me to make requests?" And the way you answer that is by looking at the documentation - not for your library (discord.py), but for the API (Discord itself).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, the ratelimit for editing a channel is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel, there's no way of "bypassing" this. You're gonna have edit the channel every 5 minutes instead.

```py
while True:
    await channel.edit(name=animation[counter])
    counter = 0 if counter + 1 == size else counter + 1
    await sleep(300)
```